# Should the networking tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

We have two networking-related tags:

- [network-programming](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network-programming) (27 questions, wiki)
- [networking](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking) (5 questions, no wiki)

Since any on-topic networking-related questions would relate to code itself (nothing otherwise on-topic on [Network Engineering SE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/)), I assume we only need one.  Plus, one question already uses both tags.

If this is to be done, I suppose the larger tag can remain while the smaller one will be merged into it (although, for merging, it doesn't matter).  This would have to be done by myself or another moderator.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: In practice, [tag:socket] is a near-synonym as well (though technically sockets include Unix-domain sockets which are local to the machine).

Comment: @200_success: That tag appears to be empty anyway.

Comment: There are 26 questions tagged [tag:socket].

Comment: @200_success: Ah, thanks for the correction.  I'm not sure about that one, but it may serve as a separate request.  These two tags may need to be situated first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would agree with the merging of the two tags, however, I would merge [network-programming](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network-programming) into [networking](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking).

Why?  This is *Code* Review.  The "programming" part of the first tag is redundant, because you have to program in order to produce code.

Just my two cents.